# How can clients without Ruby view web pages using SASS?

Tags: css, ruby, sass

If an individual is visiting a website that uses SASS and they don't have ruby installed on their machine, how is their computer able to compile the SASS into CSS so they can view the website properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't. Something on the server compiles SASS or whatever into regular CSS (and HAML or whatever into regular HTML, and Coffeescript into Javascript). Usually this is done as part of the app deployment. That said, there may be javascript-based sass translators. There's one for Less: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28stylesheet_language%29